# One roll number cant be added again

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [same roll number can not be added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829001/same-roll-number-can-not-be-added)

I want my code to behave this way that if once i had added a roll number, it can not be added again in the registration..........same as if once an email adress is registered the error displays that EMAIL ADDRESS ALREADY BEEN TAKEN....

I am creating a function . of roll numbr value is 1 it shall display error and if not 1 it shall not display the error

```
function selectroll($studentname,$rollnumber)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstuden WHERE studentname = 'studentname' and rollnumber = '$rollnumber';";
        $obj_db = new DB();
        $obj_db->query($sql);

        $row = $obj_db->rsset();
        if{
            $val = 1;
        }
        else{
            $val = 0;
        }
        $obj_db->db_close();
        return $val;
    }


        $this->_id($row[id]);
        $this->_studentname($row[studentname]);
        $this->_rollnumber($row[rollnumber]);
        $this->_classname($row[classname]);
        $obj_db->db_close();
    }


}
 ?>
```

and the function is called at the page by this method

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']) and $_GET['action'] == "Add")
{

    $val = $Tblstuden->selectroll($_POST['studentname'],$_POST['rollnumber']);
    if ($val =='1')
    {
    $Tblstuden->copyPostData();
    $Tblstuden->insert();   
    echo"asdf";
    }

    redirect("index.php?page=studentlist"); 

}

else
{
    echo"abc";

    }

?>
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?  I can definitely see syntax errors in your code: `if{ $val = 1; } else{ $val = 0; }` - this will definitely not work.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
function selectroll($studentname,$rollnumber)     
    {     
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM tblstuden WHERE studentname = 'studentname' and rollnumber = '$rollnumber';";     
        $obj_db = new DB();     
        $obj_db->query($sql);     

        $row = $obj_db->rsset();     
        if ($row){     
            $val = 1;
            $this->_id($row[id]);     
            $this->_studentname($row[studentname]);     
            $this->_rollnumber($row[rollnumber]);     
            $this->_classname($row[classname]);     

        }     
        else{     
            $val = 0;     
        }     
        $obj_db->db_close();     
        return $val;     
    }     
}     
?>
```

in line 8 of the top function - as otherwise the code won't compile.

---

Sub-note, your code is subject to mysql injection, you should look at using PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) for your database functions before you get used to the old method. Please. Do it now ;)